# What situations/champions are Manamune designed for?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been trying out Manamune on some melee mana-users lately, but I haven't been having a ton of luck as opposed to using other items. Are there some specific champions or situations that would make this item more viable?

Answer (score 5):

Manamune is an item usually for **AD Casters who use single target damage/weave auto attacks between their skills**.

The problem with this item is that it staggers your laning phase with most melee champions because you have to buy the tear first and then the item, which in turn doesn't give any good mid game stats.

**Jayce** gets it is to relieve his mana-costs, easy-stacking, his W in ranged form. Manamune is also good for single target damage like Kha'Zix, but it's difficult to be a jungler and get that item as well *without* sacrificing your mid game power.

So the champions you want to build this on: **Blue Ezreal, Jayce and Urgot** because they weave autoattacks and abilities almost constantly. It's funny but **Ryze** also enjoys the manamune because all of his abilities are single target and scale off of his mana. But why go that route when you can go Archangel's staff, right?

Most melee mana-users have better mana sustain than ranged casters, and are better to rush other items like Brutalizer or other melee items. And since most AD Melees are also considered fighters, they get things like **Frozen heart or Iceborn Gauntlet** and that relieves the mana issues too.

Comment: you forgot blitzcrank!

Comment: You can get both archangel's staff and manamune on Ryze.

Comment: I main yorick and you completely left him out, it is a MUST HAVE item on him as he relies on his ghouls for laning phase. Yorick cannot survive laning phase 95% of the time without a manamune.

Comment: @TimB While you can get BOTH Manamune and Archangel's staff on Ryze, it's not a very good idea.  1) It takes forever to stack both.  2) There are other items that are just so much better on Ryze.

Comment: @dphil They both stack at once. I'm not a Ryze expert but at least one Ryze guide does suggest that as a build.

Comment: @TimB I'm pretty sure they don't both stack at once unless they changed it somewhat recently.  You can find a guide that pretty much says anything.  I've seen a guide saying to build a Rylai's on Gangplank.

Comment: @TimB They do not stack together however it will show the second one stacking at the same rate as the first one, but once it reaches max it will reset the second and keep the first one full, this is too prevent some one from massing mana with a manamune or archangel staff.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that nobody mentioned **Yorick** yet. He is the perfect example for a melee AD caster to use Manamune, he can almost indefinitely sustain himself with his E, making him quite hard to beat in lane. Spamming his skills while also landing auto-attacks with his Q stacks his tear quite fast.

Comment: Agreed, it is a must have for him.

Answer (score 3):

**Manamune/Archangel's Staff is mostly designed for champions that benefit from large amount of maximum Mana or are very manahungry (AD casters).**

Champions that scale have abilities that scale with mana:

- **Ryze**: All his abilities, but the ultimate, scale with max Mana.
- **Blitzcrank**: He's very manahungry and his passive scales with the amount of Mana he has.
- **Kassadin**: His ultimate (Rift Walk) scales with max Mana.
- **Singed**: Singed gains bonus health equal to 25% of his maximum mana.
- **Evelynn**: While stealthed, Evelynn regenerates 1% of her maximum mana every second. (there are definitely more viable items for her)

Other:

- **Karthus**: He's really really manahungry.
- **Ezreal/Urgot/Jayce/Yorick**: They deal mostly more damage with his abilities rather than auto-attacking.
- **Pantheon**: Is also a melee AD caster but there are definitely more viable items for him.

Comment: Actually it's usually a better Idea to get the full item ASAP (if you can afford it) since it lets you stack a lot faster and thus also snowball harder. The base stats of the items are also not too bad.

Comment: @Jutschge why are you able to stack faster?

Comment: Well Manamune will give you +4 mana on every Autoattack (not only  mana used) and The Archangels staff will give you +8 mana which is basically twice as fast. Also you'll just need 300 Mana for Manamune and 350 for Archangels for it to be 100% gold efficient.

Comment: @Jutschge the not-fullstacked items dont give you +mana on autoattacks.

Comment: They will (wouldn't make sense to give + mana on a fully stacked item right? Check the [Lolwiki article about Manamune](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Manamune) for example.

Comment: @Jutschge wow! i overread that everytime!!!

Comment: O man, I wouldn't name people who like mana for the sake of Manamune.  Saying it's designed for people like Karthas, Evelynn, Singed, and Ryze is just incorrect.  If they built anything off of tear it would only be Archangels.

Comment: @dphil well that's your opinion. i just listed facts. if you say tear on ryze is just bad you are just wrong! it's an essential item! post your own answer if you think different

Comment: @PhilippSander I never anywhere said Tear on Ryze is bad.  I said Manamune on him is bad.  This is definitely not an essential item.

Comment: @dphil and i did not say manamune is good on him.

Comment: @PhilippSander Your answer makes it almost sound like it is.  Your answer puts Archangels and Manamune grouped together, but OP was **only** asking about **Manamune**.  If the question is about Manamune it's easy to make that assumption even though you do mention Archangels on the first line.  I can see what you are saying though now, but still think it's misleading.

Comment: @dphil muramana (manamune not really) is pretty strong on ryze, because the toggle passive procs when a single target spell is activated. so when the tear is already stacked, you want to build this instead of the staff

Comment: @PhilippSander Sure Muramana can be decent on Ryze but Seraph's Embrace is superior in most ways.  Seraph's gives a MASSIVE AP increase in addition to all of that mana.  In addition it gives him a huge shield that can be used.  Since Ryze is such short range he needs all of the tankiness he can get so that he doesn't get bursted.  This keeps up his machine gun damage going for a long time.  Muramana on the other hand quickly loses it's effectiveness after the first initial burst from the mana drain.  It's fine to get on a trolly build or if you don't need MR (In addition to Seraph's)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about **melee** champions that will use **manamune** effectively, I can only think  of two viable champions:

**Yorick**: Top lane, you need to get tear of the goddess ASAP it is very important for him to have it for harassment in lane with his ghouls, it gives you great sustain to be able to spam Yoricks E, which gives him more hp on use and when the ghoul itself attacks anything.

**Kha'Zix**: In top or mid lane, never jungle. Almost for the same reason Yorick needs it, allows you to have great sustain and harassment in lane be allowing him to spam his W which heals him when it hits a minion or champion and you are close enough for the effect to heal you.

With any other melee champion there are better items to get then manamune in lane or in jungle. This is all based on gold efficiency for particular champions.

Answer (score 0):

While many of the answers here have listed very good champions for the manamune, I find that many people underestimate the power it can have with Fiora.

"But Warped, taking the tear ruins Fiora's early game lane dominance!"

Yes. Yes it does. And in some cases, you don't want to be so aggressive early on. Mundo, for example, is a very good Fiora counter in my experience, because it is very difficult to burst him down and his AOE will destroy you while you're near him. With champions like Gnar, where it's difficult to get close and stay close, a more passive approach also works.

So, with all that being said, on to the mid-late game. The only unusual items in this build are the Manamune and the Essence Reaver. Aside from that, a completely normal Fiora build works fine, Lucidity boots, Cleaver, Last Whisper, and Ravenous Hydra. All together, that gives you 35% CDR, enough to use abilities frequently, armor pen, and lifesteal, as well as mana regen on hit so you can keep the Manamune on all the time.

This build can be extremely strong in the right circumstances, unlike other champions like Yorick and Kha, where it is an extremely useful item no matter what's going on, and it certainly isn't essential like it is on Jayce and Ezreal. Although, I think it's important to say that taking Manamune on Ryze is pointless because the Archangel's and Manamune both use the same mana pool, because it is a unique passive on each item.

I'll be editing in numbers tomorrow, I hope this gives some thought for now.

Comment: Fiora is actually considered one of the best Gnar counters because she has a double dash and a lot of early game burst... Manamune is the last thing you would build in that matchup because you would definitely lose the early game if you do.  Same with Mundo.  Fiora does really high damage early with a double gap closer.  This is essentially another Mundo counter because he can't safely farm vs high early damage and such gap closers.  (She has very few lanes where she has early game dominance, but those 2 matchups especially she doesn't want to ruin early game)